# Use different salt for users password hashing Yii2

Tags: yii2

I want to use a different salt for each of my user's password and I have a column in my user's table named `salt` but I don't how can I create a hash with my custom salt and how to validate password with yii2's function.

I have search yii2 docs but I found these function:

```
Yii::$app->getSecurity()->generatePasswordHash($password);
Yii::$app->getSecurity()->validatePassword($password, $hash);
```

These functions are independent of my custom salt and have their own salt for hashing.

I need something like this:

```
$hash = createHash($password, $random_string_as_salt);
$validate = validateHash($password, $hash, $random_string_as_salt);
```

Answer (score 1):

[`generatePasswordHash()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-security#generatePasswordHash()-detail) already creates hash with salt inside (unique for every user). You don't need a separate column for this. In fact you should not even try to force your own salt for password hash - cryptography is hard and there is nearly zero chance that you will make it better than default Yii2 implementation. And risk that you will make it worse, is quite high.

Just delete your column for salt and use only one for password - Yii2 will handle it in secure way.